# Why can't I use spread operator with Typescript and RXJS pipe?

Tags: typescript, rxjs

Given code like this:

```js
const pipeMethods: OperatorFunction<any, any>[] = [];

return of(req).pipe(...pipeMethods);
```

I get an error that says `A spread argument must either have a tuple type or be passed to a rest parameter`

Doing `return of(req).pipe.apply(null, pipeMethods);` instead gets me

```
Argument of type 'OperatorFunction<any, any>[]' is not assignable to parameter of type '[op1: OperatorFunction<AjaxConfig, unknown>, op2: OperatorFunction<unknown, unknown>, op3: OperatorFunction<unknown, unknown>, op4: OperatorFunction<unknown, unknown>, op5: ... 5 more ..., op6: OperatorFunction<...>]'.
```

When using a `ts-ignore` all my code functions fine. I'm having trouble understanding the error here.

Answer (score 0):

I remember seening people having problems with using the spread operator inside `pipe()` but I can't find anywhere what the problem was. Check out this GitHub issue https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/issues/3989 for some addtional info.

Anyway, I think at this moment the best way is using [`pipe`](https://rxjs.dev/api/index/function/pipe) function that comes from `rxjs` package (I'm not talking about `Observable.pipe()` now):

```
import { pipe as pipeFromArray, of } from 'rxjs';

...

const operators = [
  map(...),
  filter(...),
  tap(...),
];

const source = of('World').pipe(pipeFromArray(...operators));
```

Live demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-ggiquc

Comment: `import { of, OperatorFunction, pipe as pipeFromArray } from 'rxjs';` and then `return of(req).pipe(pipeFromArray(...pipeMethods));` still gets me spread error from TS. Meanwhile `const source = of("World").pipe(...operators);` also works with no errors in that fiddle. A difference may be my method takes an array of methods vs being defined in the file?

Comment: I don't know. The stackblitz example doesn't show any error so it should be correct.